# subtracting quantity from 2 file and update in one of the file

Tags: function, file, subtraction

If I wanted to subtract quantity from file 1 to quantity from file 2, what should I do? and update the result in quantity file 1. Below are what I've done so far.

```
void update(){
vaccine v1;
FILE *fp, *fp1;
int found = 0;
char code[50];
fp = fopen("vaccine.txt", "r");
fp1 = fopen("dist.txt", "w");
printf ("enter vaccine code to update: ");
scanf ("%s", &code);

while (fread(&v1, sizeof(vaccine), 1, fp)) {
    if (strcmp(code, v1.code) == 0) {
        found = 1;
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter distributed quantity:");
        scanf("%i, &v1.quantity");
        break;
    }
    fwrite(&v1, sizeof(vaccine), 1, fp1);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
if(found) {
    fp1 = fopen ("dist.txt", "r");
    fp = fopen("vaccine.txt", "w");
    
    while(fread(&v1, sizeof(vaccine), 1, fp)){
        v1.quantity - (while(fread()))
        
    }
}
    printf ("\n record not found");
```

}

This is how I started, the structure and when I created the file vaccine.txt

```
typedef struct vaccine {
char name [50];
char origin [50];
char code [50]; 
int dosage;
char population_covered [50];
int quantity;
```

}vaccine;

this will be the function create

```
void create (){
vaccine *v;
FILE *fp; 
int amount, i;
printf("enter amount you wished to edit: ");
scanf("%i", &amount);

v = (vaccine*)calloc(amount, sizeof(vaccine));
fp = fopen("vaccine.txt","w");

for(i=0;i<amount;i++){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's name: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", v[i].name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's code: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s]", v[i].code);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's production country: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", v[i].origin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's dosage: \n");
    scanf("%i", &v[i].dosage);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's population covered: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", v[i].population_covered);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("enter vaccine's quantity: ");
    scanf("%i", &v[i].quantity);
    fwrite(&v[i], sizeof(vaccine), 1, fp);
} 
fclose(fp);
```

}

this two are only function, I have already called it in the main code

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for us to answer, we need: a sample of your input file, the output you want, and what you have coded up to now.

Comment: I've edited it and put my code there, the user will input the distributed amount and put it in the file dist.txt but the amount should be subtracted n update with the quantity of file vaccine.txt

Comment: What is variable `i`? What is the declaration of `vaccine`?

Comment: oh yes it should be v1.quantity? and vaccine is the first file name

Comment: I mean: the declaration `vaccine v1;` doesn't describe the members of this structure. This must be defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: alright i'll put the beginning of the code